# env.php changes when enabling Varnish

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish, redis

**app/etc/env.php** has the following for **cache** settings:

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
                'port' => '0',
                'persistent' => '0',
                'database' => '0',
                'force_standalone' => '0',
                'connect_retries' => '1',
                'read_timeout' => '10',
                'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
                'compress_data' => '1',
                'compress_tags' => '1',
                'compress_threshold' => '20480',
                'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
            ]
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
                'port' => '0',
                'persistent' => '0',
                'database' => '1',
                'force_standalone' => '0',
                'connect_retries' => '1',
                'read_timeout' => '10',
                'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
                'compress_data' => '0',
                'compress_tags' => '1',
                'compress_threshold' => '20480',
                'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

I'm wondering if these should be removed or atleast the **page_cache** when enabling **varnish**?